# How to make my currently running Autosys Job to FA [Failure] , when command script fails

Tags: shell, autosys

I have a script which is in Autosys Job : `JOB_ABC_S1`

```
command : /ABC/script.sh
```

**Scrpt.sh code**

```
grep -w "ABC" /d/file1.txt

status=$?

if [ $status -eq 0 ]
then 
    echo "Passed"
else
    echo "Failed"
    exit 1
fi
```

My issue is even if the script failed or pass , the AutoSys job is marked as SU SUCCESS

I don't want it to mark it as success , if script fail's .. it should mark AutoSys as FA and if script pass then mark job to SU SUCCESS

What should i change in the script to make it happen ?

**Job :**

```
insert_job : JOB_ABC_S1
machine : XXXXXXXXXXX
owner : XXXXXXXX
box_name : BOX_ABC_S1
application : XXXX
permission : XXXXXXXXXXX
max_run_alarm : 60
alarm_if_fails : y
send_notification : n
std_out_file :  XXXXX
std_err_file :  XXXXX
command :  sh /ABC/script.sh
```

Comment: Can u pls share the complete JIL of the job

Comment: @Piyush  kindly check my updated question ,  guide me how to fail job

Comment: do let me know what you observe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first look all seems to be fine.

However, i would suggest a script modification which you can try out.
By default Autosys fails the jobs if the exit code is non-zero unless specified.

JOB JIL seems to be fine.

Please update your script as below and check for 2 things:

1. Executed job EXIT-CODE: either it should be 1 or 2. We are trying to fail the job in both the cases.
2. Str log files

Script:

```
#!/bin/sh
srch_count=$(grep -cw ABC /d/file1.txt)
if [ $srch_count -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Passed"
    #exit 0 
    exit 2
else
    echo "Failed"
    exit 1
fi
```

This way we can confirm if the exit code is correctly being captured by Autosys.

Comment: apart from this do you have any … other approach to FA job

Comment: not sure what is causing it !
Try: User-defined Exit Code in JIL with attributes success_codes or fail_codes
Change the script to run with bash -x /filename
try in any other host apart from linux or scripting language perl / python

Comment: create a cmd job with command as exit 101 
see what happens